# macOS catalina ignores shell in AD and uses zsh instead

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, catalina, active-directory

We have Catalina hosts connected to our AD domain. Directory Utility shows AD users having /bin/bash as their shell (in Directory Editor), and the default shell for the domain is /bin/bash (in Services -> User Experience). However, when I log in, Catalina ignores both and instead logs me in with zsh.

How do I get Catalina to honor the shell preference from AD?

Answer (score 1):

The instructions for enforcing a default shell for users in macOS Catalina through Active Directory is available at Apple: https://support.apple.com/guide/directory-utility/set-a-unix-active-directory-user-accounts-diru34cb1e36/mac

Here's the procedure to manually update the shell (independently of any AD setting):

If the computer a natively installed with Catalina, then all user accounts will use `zsh`.

If the computer was upgraded to Catalina, then:

- all existing accounts will use `bash` and will see a warning that `zsh` is now the preferred shell in macOS.
- all newly created accounts will use `zsh`

If a user wants to change their default shell environment from `zsh` to `bash`, the following command can be issued at the command line prompt in Terminal.app:

`chsh -s /bin/bash`

You can also change the default shell via **System Preferences** → **Users & Groups**. First unlock the padlock at the bottom-left, then control-click the user to edit and chose "Advanced options..." from the popup context menu. Edit the **Login shell** property by selecting the shell from the drop-down control.

Comment: Are you saying there's no way to have Catalina honor the shell specified for the user in AD?

Comment: The user can always override this setting, as per the documentation.